# How to scan only Advertising Packet BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

While scanning for advertising beacons with startLeScan method, this method also request peripheral device for scan response and stores it in scanRecord. I only want to scan for advertising payload I don’t want to send request scan response to peripheral device

my code to scan:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLEScanCallback);
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLEScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe there is any way to turn off scan response requests.  Android 4.3-4.4 BLE APIs provide no scanning options at all (other than a service uuid filter).  The new Android 5.0 APIs have added some scan options, but none that halt scan responses.  See here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder.html